# Android styles: how to change colors in styles.xml

Tags: android, colors, android-styles

I want to change some colors of android UI elements. But I would prefer to set a default tint color, which applies to all UI elements. I am not sure if this is possible.
If not, I want to set the "tint"-color of some UI elements, as shown below. Can anybody enlighten me?

[image: colors of text and dividers in datepicker]

[image: highlight colors of buttons]

[image: enabled color of switch]

[image: progress color of seekbar]

**EDIT**

Based on what Entreco suggested:

My styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiary">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondaryInverse">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="android:textColorTertiaryInverse">@color/brown</item>

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    </style>
    <!-- style for the action bar backgrounds -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/brown</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="background">@color/brown</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/brown_light</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And my values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/blue</item>
        <!-- <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item> -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

And in my Manifest:

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base" >
    ...
</application>
```

But the primary color is still the same...???

Comment: there is no easy way(for API < 21): 1,2 Custom dialog 3. custom drawabable as button's  background 4. custom drawable ... 5. support v7 6. custom ...

Comment: if you want to change each view attributes individually, you have to set a theme (not style) for them in XML layout. for example, just add `android: theme="@style/yourThemeHere"`

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Lollipop this is straight-forward thanks to the colorPrimary attribute:

file values/styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
</style>
```

file values-v21/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Basically, you can define a color pallete for your app, and I believe for your case your want to set the colorPrimary (unverified).

More info on [Material colors](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Comment: I think this is how it should be done. However, it has no effect in my case: see my EDIT above.

Comment: And pre-Lollipop? In ICS?